# How to visualizate svm weights in hog

Tags: opencv, svm, vision

In the original paper of HOG (Histogram of Oriented Gradients) http://lear.inrialpes.fr/people/triggs/pubs/Dalal-cvpr05.pdf there are some images, which shows the hog representation of an image (Figure 6).In this figure the f, g part says "HOG descriptor weighted by respectively the positive and the negative SVM weights".

I don't understand what does this mean. I understand that when I train a SVM, I get a Weigth vector, and to classify, I have to use the features (HOG descriptors) as the input of the function. So what do they mean by positive and negative weigths? And how would I  plot them like the paper?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I think this page could help you: http://www.geocities.ws/talh_davidc/

Answer (score 0):

The weights tell you how significant a specific element of the feature vector is for a given class. That means that if you see a high value in your feature vector you can lookup the corresponding weight

- If the weight is a high positiv number it's more likely that your object is of the class
- If your weight is a high negative number it's more likely that your object is NOT of the class
- If your weight is close to zero this position is mostly irrelavant for the classification

Now your using those weights to scale the feature vector you have where the length of the gradients are mapped to the color-intensity. Because you can't display negative color intensities they decided to split the positive and negative visualization. In the visualizations you can now see which parts of the input-image contributes to the class (positiv) and which don't (negative).